# R: combine mtext() with points() - correct way to specify coordinates?

Tags: r, text, plot, coordinates, point

I want to combine a text I place in the margins with `mtext()` with a graphics object that I create either using `points()` or `polygon()`. The following example roughly works for me with the default plot settings:

```
plot(1)
mtext("This is a red dot:", side=1, line=2, cex=0.8)
par(xpd=T)
points(1.08, 0.512, pch=15, cex=1.5, col="red")
```

However, using `plot(1:10)` instead or prefixing it with `windows(8,8)` puts the dot in the wrong position, as `points()` takes user coordinates. Is there a way to get my dot placed correctly independent of plot limits or device size?

Comment: Do you want to add points in the margin as in a `legend`? Or do you want to place text inside the graph? For the latter see `?text` which uses graph coordinates.

Comment: @Jan van der Laan: I want to place the mtext() and points() outside the plot. Using the legend() command is not an option, as it imposes a particular style. The example I gave does what I want, but is fragile as it depends both on xlim/ylim and width/height of the plot. As I will need to use this with different plots, I need a way to make the points nicely align with the mtext that is independent of these settings. Using text() with par(xpd=T) to write outside the plotting area is not an option, as it is not independent of xlim/ylim.

Comment: Check out `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` to convert between the different coordinate types, e.g. user, device and figure.

Comment: @koekenbakker: I have identified the correct position using locator() and converted to ndc, nfc and nic. None of these stay stable when I resize the plot. Any other ideas? Is there any way to get the borders of the mtext back from the function call and simply pace the dot to the right of that?

Comment: No straightforward way that I know of. You could try `strwidth` and `strheight` to [calculate the position](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r-help-archive/nyCdRPma5YI), but don't know how stable these are with resizing. Another option is to add a small empty plot below the main one just for the 'legend' with `layout` and send your text and graphics to that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found an answer that works based on the suggestions of @koekenbakker. To make it look pretty, some minor adjustments are still necessary to get the dot in line with the text, but it seems to work well independent of plot size and axis limits (but you cannot resize the plot once created). To do the adjustments on the exact position of the point, I would recommend using fractions of `strheight("O", cex=0.8)` and `strheight("O", cex=0.8)` for this example (which uses `cex=0.8` for demonstration).

```
plot(1)
mtext("This is a red dot:", side=1, line=2, cex=0.8, col="green") ## place sample text at bottom of figure
par(xpd=T) ## enable plotting outside plot region
textXPos <- mean(par("usr")[1:2]) ## x position is middle of plot
textYPos <- par("usr")[3] - strheight("O") * 4 ## y position is below bottom of plot (line 2 = 4 * height of letter O)
text(textXPos, textYPos, "This is a red dot:", cex=0.8, col="red", adj=c(0.5, 0)) ## this text overlaps - y position is correct
pointXPos <- textXPos + 0.5 * strwidth("This is a red dot:", cex=0.8) ## text is centred, so need to move half of the text width to the right
points(pointXPos, textYPos, pch=16, col="red") ## still needs minor adjustments to x and y position to make it look nice
```